# ASP.NET Core 5 data-ajax attributes not applied in form submit through a function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET Core 5, I want to partial update div with response from server.

In ASP.NET, there was Ajax.BeginForm, which worked fine.  But this helper tag was not carried to ASP.NET Core.  Hence my path to misery with my attempt at raw form invoking ajax.

If I use HTML form with submit button like this:

```
<form data-ajax="true" id="rawform" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-mode="replace-with" data-ajax-update="#ajupd" action="/Test/_PartOfView">
    <input id="aj2" type="text" name="aVal" value="came from ajax form before button click" />
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />&nbsp;RAW form with button <b>---- THIS WORKS!!!!!!!!!</b>
</form>
```

all works, although I get a complaint from the debugger that it wants me to do asynchronous rather than synchronous.  I take this to mean I am correctly accessing “jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js”.

What does not work: create a button with onclick to invoke function to do the submit.  Function is

```
function doAjax4() {
        $("#rawform").submit();            
    }
```

-- it seems all the data-ajax attributes are ignored.  I can add method=post, and response comes back, but as a new view, not a partial update.

I got ajax calls working easily with

$.ajax(……….)

but I don’t know how add a verification token using this style.

Why does the function submit of a form not recognize the ajax attributes data-ajax, data-ajax-method, etc?

Comment: I figured out how to add AntiForgery token using $.ajax.  So I'll just go that route.

Comment: Maybe Json is best way to do this kind of thing.  I don't know enough about Core Pages to know if there's a better way to do it using Pages.

Comment: those attributes are a part of " jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX" library.  When you submit a form the browser will do just that and ignore the custom attributes that it doesn't understand.  (so jQuery Unobtrusive is actually preventing normal form submission and handling it on it's own [by injecting a handler]...)  Your JS there is triggering a normal form submission.

Comment: to further explain... the way an "ajax" call works is the javascript sends the POST request and the same script gets the results back from the server. (in a callback)  It then populates the DOM.  A standard form submission the browser sends the POST and the browser gets the results/response directly (which is usually a full page load/redirect after the server processes the data...)

Comment: But same JS form submission worked fine in ASP.NET EF using jQuery Unobtrusive AJAX.

Comment: not sure why it would work in one version and not the other... I do know that I had to re-write the layout to remove the "@RenderBody()" piece for my own js functions to work properly.  I was getting some odd behavior of POST/GET/POST sometimes.  So a double post with the @RendyBody in there.

Comment: OK.  Thanks. .......